# Script for Exporting File Metadata to CSV?

Tags: terminal, csv, file-metadata

DISCLAIMER: I am not a developer and don't have much knowledge of coding; however, what I want to do seems simple enough.

I use Pro Tools and want to run a terminal script in Mac OS to be able to scan/run through all .aaxplugin files in finder to copy their name and version number onto a spreadsheet or text file. I literally just want the name of the file/plugin and version number. Where should I start? Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's unclear how to read the version numbers from these `.aaxplugin` files. Is it part of the filename? Where are the files stored? Does the application that they are plugins for contain this information?

Answer (score 0):

It seems .aaxplugins are binary files containing executable code for professional audio workstation software.

So, chances are, there's little scripting tools outside these workstation software that can read a name and a version number from these files.

In that case, you'll have to learn the scripting language suppored by your software (pro tools), and use it to open one plugin after the other, read that information and print it somewhere.

Comment: That makes sense however I know I can see all the info I need to with finder. Is there a way to extrapolate information from the finder “Get Info”?

Comment: ah! interesting! Quite possibly there is, but I'm not OS X programmer enough to know, sorry!

Comment: All good! Thanks for the reply!